# Java Async Http clients comparisons

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am evaluating an HTTP client libraries for my application. This is a web application which calls various web services, aggregates content and then sends it to Ajax client. I think I need an async client because I  want to release my application server (Tomcat) thread while I am waiting for long response from web service, so that Tomcat can reuse this thread to do something else while I am doing IO to target web service.

I found 3 libraries out there

1. Apache HttpClient 4.x
2. Jetty Http Client
3. Sonotype Http Client (former Ning)

Wondering how this libraries compares.

I can see that Sonotype client can use pluggable providers for http handling, including Apache Http Client 3.x. What I don't see what I am loosing if I am using Apache Http 4.x client directly and not through Sonotype client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous HTTP Client for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014528/asynchronous-http-client-for-java)

Answer (score -1):

You should consider ning. It is intensively used in play2's web service client under the hood. And as a play2's user all I should know about it - it just runs pretty well and fast.

Answer (score -5):

look at the API they are quite different, take the one you prefer.
the benchmark are a bit riduclous, I think you never neeed that speed.